# Laravel classloader failed to open file under stress test

Tags: php, laravel, iis, laravel-4, stress-testing

I have a website made with laravel 4.2

Individual requests work fine, but under stress tests (just 20 simultaneous requests), the site fails.

```
production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'include(D:\wwwroot\SITENAME\vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in D:\wwwroot\SITENAME\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:412
```

The above error is a sample of the error, it is not always the same file that can't be found. The file it can't find always exists on disk.

My guess is some operation (file IO) fails early on in the request lifecycle, causing subsequent look ups to fail.

The site is running on IIS.

Comment: Why would you run PHP on IIS?

Comment: @lukasgeiter LAMP is just one stack, or do you have a reason not to use PHP on IIS pertaining to laravel bootstrapers performance during simultaneous connections?

Comment: I'm sorry. I know it wasn't a very helpful comment. It's just that every time I've worked with IIS I had a lot of problems, so I can't imagine why someone would choose IIS for a PHP application. But I'm sure you have your reasons...

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather be on a unix base but c'est la vie. Aside from DB drivers it hasn't been too bad. Long story short, we are running other services as part of the site which require IIS, using PHP means we can move everything to OS stack when All composite parts are platform independent.

Comment: Okay :) Is it always the same file that failes to be included? (I assume not?)

Comment: No, it can be quite random. Usually a file from the laravel framework, sometimes even a model from the application itself. Most of the time everything is fine though, but some requests fail 1/500 maybe, and 1/3 during stress testing, each with a failure to open a file excepion